Can you spell memento as mement?
I recently ordered a shirt because the design was cool and it's from a game I liked. I just got it in the mail yesterday, and when I looked further, it seems like the design says 'mement' instead of 'momento' as in 'memento mori'. I asked both my friend and a subreddit for whether or not that was an alternative spelling variation and got mixed results. Is it a spelling error, because if so I want to return it. It looks like the official movie poster also has the same spelling, so could it be a translation error from Japanese?

It might be illuminating to point out that the approach of English speakers to Latin is often uncannily similar to the approach of Japanese speakers to English, the major difference being of course that there are still native speakers of English around. So Latin in the hands of Japanese speakers doesn't really have a chance.

It's 100% a spelling error. Memento is the singular imperative, and the plural imperative is mementote. That's it. Other forms of this verb use the perfect stem memin- As you can see from this conjugation chart, mement is not a form possible with this verb.
Note though that it's also not momento. That would come from a different word, the noun momentum.
Edit:
Bringing in Sebastian's comments about Japanese, which are helpful here. In transliterating English words, Japanese adds an -o when the word ends in a -t:

English internet becomes internetto (インターネット) in Japanese.
English test becomes tesuto (テスト) in Japanese.

This is because Japanese words, with few exceptions, must end in a vowel. Usually -u is added, but for -t, adding a -u to it changes the sound to -tsu, though you do see this sometimes, as in the Japanese shatsu (シャツ), from the English shirt.
Perhaps in working backwards, it's assumed that the final o- in memento is from Japanese, and so they drop it to find the original word, just like they would with moment, as seen from this dictionary, where it's spelled momento in Japanese (モメント). I'm not sure how common モメント is, but I did find it in JMdict.

It is absolutely possible that it is a mistake caused by the Japanese alphabet. In Japanese you cannot write closed syllables (except those ending in -n), only open ones like mo, ko, to, etc. So when the Japanese want to transcribe a word like moment (and despite all Japanese knowning the Latin alphabet too, they're quite transcription happy), they can only transcribe it as momento. Therefore, when a Japanese reads memento (メメント), he cannot tell whether it was originally memento or mement.

… and by analogy with moment, and not being too familiar with Latin, one could easily assume it must have been mement. A quick Google search finds many Japanese websites using this particular misspelling. There is even a restaurant of that name in Kyoto (quamquam hic titulus haud cauponae idoneus mihi videtur).

@SebastianKoppehel I saw your second comment first, which gave me the same idea you had. Then I read your first comment. D'oh! I think you're absolutely right here, so I expanded on it a bit in an edit.

@Sebastian Koppehel: You are discussing Japanese, in English, on a Latin website and your native tongue is German. I'm impressed. Which language do you think in?

@tony Nonne tu quoque interdum Latine somnias?
